# Removing an edge from a minimum spanning tree

Tags: algorithms

I am studying algorithms, and i have seen an exercise saying the following:

> Let $G$ be a weighted graph. Let $T$ be an MST for $G$. Assume that an edge in $G$ is
>       deleted. Describe an algorithm that finds an MST of the new graph in time proportional 
>       to the number of edges in $G$.

My question is, i think the graph is now not a connected graph because we deleted an edge from a MST. So now do i have to find all MST for each disconnected part? I appreciate for any help.

Thank you

Comment: We delete an edge from $G$, not from $T$!

Comment: @martini oh you are right, then this problem is just finding a MST for a graph right?

Comment: Also, new graph may or may not be disconnected, does that mean that i need to find MST for every connected part if the graph is disconnected?

Comment: I don't know what you have to do then, but I think it suffices that your algorithm stops then with a "$G - e$ is disconnected" message